# Objectify: delay between "put()" and object being found with "query()"

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm using Objectify to store items in a database, and want to enforce uniqueness on the "name" field. I'm starting with a trivial implementation, before I start worrying about race conditions...

Here's how I add the object to the database:

```
Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();

if (ofy.query(Item.class).filter("name", name).count() == 0) {
    Item newItem = new Item(name);
    ofy.put(newItem);
}
```

If I attempt to insert an object several times quickly, sometimes I'll be able to create three or four before the filter finds existing objects and prevents a new one being saved.

This is running locally - so hasn't been deployed to Google App Engine yet.

Should I be worried? Am I missing something obvious? I haven't explicitly enabled caching on the Item class.

(The dev environment is "Google Plugin for Eclipse" v1.5.2, Objectify 3.0)

Comment: Ah, got it. Looks like indexes are written asynchronously, so may not appear in a fetch() resultset immediately.

More information here:
http://groups.google.com/group/objectify-appengine/browse_thread/thread/2395c585161a5274/997c916eecf00f38

Comment: That's correct. Also, the HRD datastore is eventually consistent for queries, which may also be causing this. You should post your comment as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This HRD behavior is solved by using @Parent attribute and ancestor queries. See also http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/AdvancedPatterns and http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/hr/overview.html

Comment: well using @Parent causes all Items to be placed into the same Entity group, which will cause the application to start getting ConcurrentModificationException a lot more when multiple users access the application at once. Basically this makes the application unable to scale past a few 10s or 100s of concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to force transaction by commit?

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Transactions